# Error while trying to install OpenSTF

Tags: android

I am trying to install Open stf. Stf Doctor says the following error. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling. But I see the same error.

```
2017-12-06T06:56:36.285Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] OS Arch: x64
2017-12-06T06:56:36.287Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] OS Platform: darwin
2017-12-06T06:56:36.287Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] OS Platform: 16.7.0
2017-12-06T06:56:36.287Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] Using Node 9.2.0
2017-12-06T06:56:36.309Z ERR/cli:doctor 27642 [*] Unexpected error checking ZeroMQ: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/build/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/build/Debug/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/out/Debug/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/Debug/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/out/Release/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/Release/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/build/default/zmq.node
 → /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stf/node_modules/zmq/compiled/9.2.0/darwin/x64/zmq.node
2017-12-06T06:56:36.311Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] Using GraphicsMagick 1.3.26
2017-12-06T06:56:36.311Z ERR/cli:doctor 27642 [*] ProtoBuf version cannot be detected
2017-12-06T06:56:36.313Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] Using ADB 1.0.39
2017-12-06T06:56:36.315Z INF/cli:doctor 27642 [*] Using RethinkDB 2.3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

STF is known to support node 8.17.0 only, install the specific node version and check.

Also delete the node_modules folder in stf folder and try npm install again using the right node version, zmq issue should be resolved then